# What is the meaning of \0 in perl?

Tags: perl

```
$a = "aaata";
$b = "aataa";
$count = ($a ^ $b) =~tr/\0//c;
```

output 2 (because of two miss matches perform by the `c` flag)
without using `c` flag output is `3`(matches)

Here what is the use of `\0` in `tr`. Without using `tr`, script gives the some gibberish character. I don't know what is this and use of `tr` in here and use of the `\0`. Apart from this where we use the `\0` in perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, an escape sequence consisting of up to three octal digits will insert a character with that code point, so `\40` or `\040` produce a space character, and `\0` produces an ASCII NUL

The code is counting the number of characters that are *different* between `$a` and `$b`

It does a bitwise XOR on the two strings. Any characters that are identical will XOR together to zero, producing a NUL character. The `tr/\0//c` counts the number of characters in the resulting string that *other than NULs* (because of the `/c` modifier) so it will return 2 in this case because the two strings are different at the third and fourth character positions

Dumping the value of the expression `$a ^ $b` shows this clearly

```
"\0\0\25\25\0"
```

The `tr///` counts the two `\25` characters, ignoring all NULs

Answer (score 2):

The [bitwise string operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-String-Operators) `^` returns the byte-wise [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) of each byte in its two [bit string](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Bit-Strings) operators. So

```
$a = "aaata"; $b = "aataa";
printf "%vX\n", ($a ^ $b);
```

gives

```
0.0.15.15.0
```

because `ord("a" ^ "a") == 0`, and `ord("a" ^ "t") == 0x15` and `ord("t" ^ "a") == 0x15` since the ASCII representation for `"a"` is hexadecimal `0x61` and binary 
`0b0110_0001` (try `printf "%b\n", ord "a"`) and the ASCII value of "t" is `0x74` or binary `0b0111_0100`.

Now, taking XOR of `0b0110_0001` and `0b0111_0100` gives `0b0001_0101` or hexadecimal `0x15`.

The purpose of the [transliteration operator `tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) in `tr/\0//c` is now to count the number of nonzero bytes 
in the 5 character long string.

According to the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

> **tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr**
>
> Transliterates all occurrences of the characters found in the search
>   list with the corresponding character in the replacement list. It
>   returns the number of characters replaced or deleted.

and

> If the `/c` modifier is specified, the `SEARCHLIST` character set is
>   complemented.

and

> If the `REPLACEMENTLIST` is empty, the `SEARCHLIST` is replicated. This
>   latter is useful for counting characters in a class or for squashing
>   character sequences in a class.

Further [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Character-Escapes) documents the meaning of `\0`. It is an octal escape sequence:

> **Octal escapes**
>
> There are two forms of octal escapes. Each is used to specify a
>   character by its code point specified in octal notation.

So `tr/\0//c` is equivalent to `tr/\001-\377/\001-\377/`<sup>1</sup> and hence it will count any nonzero characters.

**Footnotes:**

<sup>1. Usage of octal escapes on the form `\xxx` are discouraged for numbers greater than `\077`, see [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Character-Escapes) for more information. Hence, `tr/\001-\377//` is better written using the `\o{}` escape as `tr/\o{1}-\o{377}//`</sup>